# od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef() AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'

Tags: tensorflow, import, object-detection-api

I have a mac and I am using tensorflow 2.0, python 3.7.
I am following the tutorial for creating an object detection model for real-time application.
but i am getting the following error:

```
"Downloads/models/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.py", line 43, in <module>
    od_graph_def = tf
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'
```

below is the tutorial link:

I checked the environment and I already have tensorflow environment in anaconda

```
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
 
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
 
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops


from utils import label_map_util
 
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
 
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
 
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')
 
NUM_CLASSES = 90


opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
 
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

Answer (score 84):

Yeah, the syntax has changed in T2.0. Here's the correct piece:

```
tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()   # -> instead of tf.GraphDef()
tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile()   # -> instead of tf.gfile.GFile()
```

Answer (score 29):

I had similar issues, when upgraded to Python 3.7 and Tensorflow 1.2.0 to Tensorflow 2.0.0

If you don't want to touch your code, just add these 2 lines in the main.py file w/ Tensorflow code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

And that's it!!
**NOW** Everything should runs seamlessly :)

But if you write new code, indeed (as was mentioned above) change these calls:

```
  with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
```

To:

```
  with tf.io.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
utils_ops.tf = tf.compat.v1
tf.gfile = tf.io.gfile
```

Adding these lines might fix your problem