# Error: Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile' error while running tensorflow object detection api tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to use the object detection tutorial from tensor flow api. I am using python 3 and tensor flow version 2. But getting the below error.I tried several ways:

```
File "C:\Aniruddhya\object_detection\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 137, in load_labelmap
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
```

can someone help me to run this?
code link: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/3/folders/1XHpnr5rsENzOOSzoWNTvRqhEbLKXaenL

Comment: So where is the code that you are getting this error from?  Did you install the module using pip?

Comment: Thaks Murray for your reply.I have installed all the modules in ananconda using pip install. Its a standard code present in the tesnor flow api documentation .Here it goes:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XHpnr5rsENzOOSzoWNTvRqhEbLKXaenL

Comment: You should add your relevant code to the posting, so that its easier for people to view it (as well as be available in the future when other people have similar issues)

Comment: I am bit new to Stackoverflow.Yet to know how to upload a code.Thats why I have given the gdrive link.

Comment: Just copy & paste the code within your Question area; that'll do.

Comment: This worked for me, check it out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58222195/9895080

Answer (score 15):

It's not called that in TensorFlow 2. You might be using a TensorFlow 1 tutorial.

Version 1
`tf.gfile.GFile`
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile

Version 2
`tf.io.gfile.GFile`
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile

Answer (score 8):

If you have Tensorflow version 2. You can use the next module compatible with the version 1, too.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by reinstalling tensor using the previous version: sudo pip3 install tensorflow==1.14.0

Answer (score 1):

You may optionally downgrade to previous version of tensorflow:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.12.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

otherwise , make if tf.io.gfile and import tf.io