# I've tried tf.io.gfile, still results in "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, config, attributeerror

This error is shown when I run
`config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-efc7822bb0d7> in <module>
----> 1 config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py in get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config_path, config_override)
     92   """
     93   pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
---> 94   with tf.io.gfile.GFile(pipeline_config_path, "r") as f:
     95     proto_str = f.read()
     96     text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
```

Comment: have you seen this SO ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363136/error-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-gfile-error-while-running-tensorfl

Comment: it will be helpful if you state the version of your tensorflow as well

Comment: tf version is 2.4.1

Comment: Yes, I've tried that out, nothing changes

Comment: hmmmm that's weird. according to the official documentation, that should be the correct way to use it https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.4/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile.
not sure whats going on

Comment: I'm tired now, trying to solve this error for 10+ days

Comment: are you using anaconda perhaps? maybe there are problems with the environment? try to print tf.__version__ and see if the version is actually 2.4.1, since once i have problem where the tensorflow version installed is different than the version it use

Comment: Using anaconda, printed tf.__version__ . Shows the exact same 2.4.1

Comment: Thanks for your time Vinson, I've just sort it out!