# Tensorflow 1 to Tensorflow 2 conversion code - detection_graph.as_default() Attribute Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was running this code with `TensorFlow1`

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

Since it does not work on `TensorFlow2` I converted the code to [According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58222195/11167163):

```
detection_graph = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
  with tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

but it trigger the following error :

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
AttributeError: as_default
```

Do anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tensorflow 1 use like,

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
detection_graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
```